# Why doesn't useState work correct in react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

So, i have a useState:

```
const [number, setNumber] = useState(mid);
```

And a function

```
function sNum() {
    newMid = mid;
    setNumber(newMid);
  }
```

So, when i launch the function sNum() here, it don't work correct:

```
function lower() {
    end = mid;
    mid = (begin + end) / 2;
    sNum();
    Alert.alert(JSON.stringify("Ваше число больше / меньше / равно " + mid.toFixed() + "?"));
```

There are all other variables and hooks:

```
const [max, setMax] = useState();
  let begin = 0;
  let end = max;
  let mid = (begin + end) / 2;
  let newMid = mid;
```

Error is:
When number is 25(just for example) and i click to higher, it gives me 25050.

```
function higher() {
    begin = mid;
    mid = (begin + end) / 2;
    Alert.alert(JSON.stringify("Ваше число больше / меньше / равно " + mid.toFixed() + "?"));
    sNum()
  }
```

Comment: Have you tried passing 'mid' as param to function sNum instead of passing nothing?

Comment: Hi, your query needs more info. Is there any error that you are getting. What is the error? Also try putting more code, if possible.